# How to fire onChange event on custom components using react-testing-library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-testing-library

I'm using this component:

```
<AceEditor
  value={data}
  className="code-editor"
  mode="json"
  theme="dracula"
  onChange={setData}
  name="data"
  height="320px"
  width="100%"
  editorProps={{ $blockScrolling: true }}
  showPrintMargin={false}
  highlightActiveLine={false}
/>
```

So, using react-testing-library how can I get this component and fire an *onChange* event? I tried to find some function like *getByComponentName* or similar but without success.

Comment: need more info, if u are using react-ace, https://github.com/securingsincity/react-ace. Declare a function and call it on `onChange`

Comment: Ok @SaahithyanVigneswaran but how can I trigger this function on the spec?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in RTL you don't really do that.

The suggested approach is to simulate what a user would do. For example, if `AceEditor` renders a `textarea` you can use `fireEvent.change` to simulate a user typing. At that point, your component will fire the `onChange` event and react as it would in production.

Some 3rd party components might be too hard to test with this approach because they have an internal structure that you don't control. In those cases, I suggest to just mock them out. In the end, they are already tested by their maintainers.

In your case, you could use `jest.mock` and render a `textarea` instead of your editor.

Comment: is this really works? i can't mock the AceEditor, becaus when i mock the AceEditor it override all the ace-builds import, can anyone help me with this? or do you have any article how to mock AceEditor with textarea?